# Unique ID generated twice with uniqid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following but I am getting the error message that says that a key should be unique and it's referring to the span. [uniqid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid)

```
  ...

  const displayResults = (list: any) => {
    const slicedList = list.slice(0, 3)

    const html =
      slicedList.map((p: string | Address) => {
        if (typeof p === 'object') {
          return <span key={`id-${uniqid()}`}>{addressToString(p)}</span>
        }
        return <span key={`id-${uniqid()}`}>{p}</span>
      })

    if (list.length > 3) {
      html.push(elipsis)
    }

    return html
  }
```

Shouldn't `uniqid` generate a unqiue value?

Comment: What are you using to call `uniqid()`? As far as I know `uniqid()` is native function of PHP not JS.

Comment: What is `uniqid`?

Comment: What is the value of `uniqid()`? Are you sure it's not null?

Comment: const unique_id = uniqid(); // assign the value once, and don't do two calls of the uniqid()

Comment: It is JSX? You don't need to use uniqid() - it is not right

Comment: I would rather use `index` of your `map()` function so you don't have to use external library and increase dependency count of your app. Id has to be unique only in explicit array.

Comment: When you inspect the output, what values are you getting for your keys?

Answer (score 3):

No need to use a uniqid. Use `p` as a `key` for your component.
Read for list and keys in React documentation.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

```
const displayResults = (list: any) => {
  const slicedList = list.slice(0, 3)    
  const html = slicedList.map((p: string | Address, index) => {
     if (typeof p === 'object') {
        return <span key={`id-${addressToString(p)}`}>{addressToString(p)}</span>
     }
     return <span key={`id-${p}`}>{p}</span>
  })
    
  if (list.length > 3) {
     html.push(elipsis)
  }
    
  return html
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a better option that this `uniqId` stuff, it will generate consistent keys across multiple re-renders. Even if the OP could get the uniqId stuff working, it looks like every time the map rendered it would regenerate ids for each item, making the `key`s completely useless

Comment: One recommendation would be to include the `index` of the address as part of the key to avoid duplicate keys if there is the same address string twice in the list.

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling uniqid() twice, put the value in a const

> const UID = uniqid();

then make use of it in your code

> `${UID}`

Comment: but it will generate one unique id and use it for all of the list items... It needs to be unique for each item

Comment: that depends on where you make the call to uniqid(), do it when you need a new id